# Lenovo Ideapad P400 Touch RAM Upgrade Questions

Tags: windows-8.1, memory, lenovo-laptop, ddr3

I am a tab-hoarder and capable of accumulating multiple google chrome windows at once. Each with enough tabs that I need to use Ctrl+Tab to navigate because the tabs appear blank and are too small to click. All idling in the background while I'm streaming, downloading torrents and with several PDFs or word docs in the mix for good measure. Don't know much about RAM but I have a Lenovo Ideapad P400 Touch running Windows 8.1 and Speccy told me I have:

- Type DDR3
- Size 8192 MBytes
- Channels #    Dual
- DRAM Frequency    798.1 MHz

with 2 slots, each with:

- Size  4096 MBytes
- Manufacturer  Hyundai Electronics
- Max Bandwidth PC3-12800 (800 MHz)
- Part Number   HMT451S6AFR8C-PB

A quick google search of the same brand led me to [these two 8GB chips](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Hynix-16GB-2X8GB-DDR3-1600-PC3L-12800-1600MHz-204pin-Sodimm-laptop-Memory-Ram/351439553319?_trksid=p2047675.c100011.m1850&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20140602152332%26meid%3D3758938ef09f44c5a8f871553555c3db%26pid%3D100011%26rk%3D5%26rkt%3D10%26sd%3D360613897466):

I've read that I should use identical chips from the same manufacturer but I want to make sure I'm not overlooking any crucial information like...

A) Should I be reading up on my CPU or motherboard? Or am I safe with just finding bigger DDR3 chips of the same manufacturer (ie, two 8GB Hynix/Hyundai? DDR3 chips)?

B) How necessary is it for me to understand: nonECC vs ECC, DIMM vs LDIMM, Unbuffered vs Registered, or whatever other RAM variables I see differentiating RAM chips of the same model?

C) Hypothetically speaking, could I order two [16GB chips](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BEJM07M), snap em' in and go nutz?

D) Recommending your favorite RAM guide or youtube video would also likely be beneficial and certainly be much appreciated :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Googling Ideapad P400 specs](https://www.google.com/search?q=Ideapad+P400+specs&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) yielded [this page](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/pd026485) showing your laptop supports up to 16GB of DDR3 1600 or 1333MHz type/speed. So that ebay memory would work, however I'd suggest buying it from a more reputable place myself ([newegg link to some](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&IsNodeId=1&N=100007609%20600213067%20600564396%20600564397%20600006178))

- A) Always lookup the manual/specs for your model, as I detailed above. The CPU/motherboard lookup might be a bit confusing...
- B) Necessary enough so you don't by memory that won't work. They are all different types, generally ECC, RDIMM, Registered are server/specialty types that a normal laptop/desktop wouldn't use
- C) Yup
- D) I love [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIMM) & [newegg](http://www.newegg.com/product/CategoryIntelligence.aspx?Subcategory=147)

Also if getting multiple sticks of memory try to match their speed else they all be crippled by the slowest stick (ex: 8GB 1333MHz & 8GB 1600MHz causes both sticks to operate at 1333MHz)

Comment: I checked out that spec page you posted and it seems to conflict with what Speccy and my Windows 8.1 System Specs say. My Lenovo Ideapad definitely has an Intel Core i7-3632QM processor and according to the following link... http://ark.intel.com/products/71458  Intel states that this CPU can handle up to 32GB of RAM. Does this figure include virtual memory or can this CPU handle 2 x 16GB or 32GB total physical memory?

Comment: That is a generic spec page for your model. A PC model can possibly support multiple processor, display, & other part types so that's not a surprise. As stated in response (A) the CPU/motherboard adds complexity simply because the CPU may support that much memory, but that doesn't mean the motherboard/UEFI/BIOS will support it (the never-ending IT compatibility matrix!). Virtual Memory is stored on the hard disk drive, CPU cache is a small bit of memory on the CPU for its computations & is usually not accessible for common use. Please don't forget to upvote or accept my answer if it helped

Answer (score -1):

Your CPU may be able to handle 32GB of RAM, but, your motherboard may not. Most Idea Pads are limited to 8-16GB of RAM. Check your Manual or Specs to see the max amount of Ram it can handle. Otherwise, you could put in 32GBs of RAM but the computer may only see 8GB. I can't imagine what you could be doing that would require more than 8GB of RAM. Check your Task Manager the next time you have 5, 10, 50 operations going at the same time and see just how much RAM you are actually using. I doubt it will be more than 2.5-4GB><
Turn your computer OFF once in a while. The next re-start will "reset" the RAM and get rid of all those "remembered" items (stored memory) that you are no longer using. Just doing this once in a while will usually clear up 1-3GB of RAM.   If you are worried about losing your OPEN tabs just set your browser to "restart where you left off". It will automatically re-open all the tabs that you had not previously closed.

**RAM REQUIREMENTS:** 2GB-Good only for stripped-down tablets, budget Chromebooks.
4GB-Minimum for budget Windows and MacOS systems, great for Chromebooks.
8GB-Excellent for Windows and MacOS systems and most gaming.
16GB-Ideal for professional work (Video Editing and large Spreadsheets) and, the most demanding of games.

> 32GB: Enthusiasts and purpose-built workstations only.

I would spend my monies on an SSD or SSHDD hard drive instead. Now that would be money well spent and truly enhance your enjoyment of your computer.

Comment: The OP describes in the question what they’re doing that can easily chew up 8GB of RAM.

Comment: An earlier answer already shows that the Ideapad P400 supports up to 16 GB. This answer does nor seem to provide any information that applies to the question.

Comment: 16GB of RAM is the MAX for the P400. But, I can see nowhere where he could be using more than 8GB of RAM. He could have a hundred "Windows" idling in the background, three streaming movies going at the same time, and 10 Word docs and still not use nearly that much RAM. But, if he wants 16GB of RAM then God Bless.

Comment: Author never asked about 32 GB they asked a out an 16 GB upgrade.  You share a great deal of information unfortunately most of isn’t applicable to the authors question

Comment: The author did state: "C) Hypothetically speaking, could I order two 16GB chips, snap em' in and go nutz?". 2x16=32GB
I may be wrong in what I offered but I didn't just write my response to the Author. There are many out there who may benefit from my answer; at least I hope so. I found this thread Googling a question I had and I saw the Author's dilemma so I offered my knowledge in hopes that either the Author or someone else might benefit from it.
Keep an open mind and an open heart. I am just trying to be helpful.